# Drawing graphics on GLControl OpenTK

Tags: winforms, opengl, opentk

I am building a graphing application using GLControl winforms. The user should be able to zoom in any area on the graph. I thought of allowing the user to draw a rectangle whenever the he holds down the mouse left button and drags it. The new zoomed in screen will have the coordinates of that rectangle. I implemented `System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle` in the `GlControl1_MouseMove` but it is not drawing anything although the event fires-checked with a break point.

```
  private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            load_Model(); ///Function for setting up the shaders
            glControl1.Invalidate();
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10.0); 
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
            _timer.Start();

        }
    private void Form4_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    { 
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.UseProgram(shader.Use());
        glControl1.SwapBuffers();
    }

   private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            glControl1.Invalidate();
        }

   Vector2 mousePos;
    private void GlControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDown)
        {
            Pen drwaPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(mousePos.X), Convert.ToInt32(mousePos.Y), Math.Abs(e.X-Convert.ToInt32(mousePos.X)), Math.Abs(e.Y-Convert.ToInt32(mousePos.Y)));
            System.Drawing.Graphics Formgraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            Formgraphics.DrawRectangle(drwaPen, rect);
        }

    }

    private void GlControl1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mousePos = new Vector2(e.X, e.Y);
            isDown = true;
        }
    }

    private void GlControl1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDown = false;
    }
```

Do I need to modify anything in the `Paint` function?

Comment: GLControl displays an OpenGL window. It is incompatible with `System.Drawing`.

Comment: So is there any other way in opengl where I can draw a rectangle by mouse movement?

Comment: You have to draw [Line primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives). But don't draw them in the mouse move event callback. You have to draw the line primitives in  `Form4_Paint_1`

Comment: I will try. Thanks!